# Convert an R container name to character

Tags: r

How to convert a container name to a character since I got a error using the following code:

```
tenv = new.env()
evalq({    }, tenv)

y = function(myEnv) {
  print(as.character(myEnv))
}

y(tenv)

Error in as.character(myEnv) :
cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain the problem you want this function to solve, since I'm going to hazard a guess there's probably a simpler way to do it.

Comment: Maybe you can give some example output?  My best guess right now is that you want it to print "tenv".  In which case you probably want to look into `substitute` or `match.call`

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to grab the name of the object passed to the `myEnv` argument, then one common idiom is `deparse(substitute( ))`. The function can be written as:

```
y <- function(myEnv) {
  deparse(substitute(myEnv))
}
```

which in use gives

```
> tenv = new.env()
> evalq({    }, tenv)
> y(tenv)
[1] "tenv"
```

[Note I don't explicitly `print` the result of `deparse(substitute( ))`, I just return it and leave the printing up to the R environment]

Another way to do this is to grab the matched function call with `match.call()` and then extract from the resulting language object the bit you want. For example:

```
yy <- function(myEnv) {
  .call <- match.call()
  .call[[2]]
}
```

which in use gives

```
> yy(tenv)
tenv
> yy(myEnv = tenv)
tenv
```

Comment: Many Thanks, Gavin! Your answer is very helpful to me. Also thank Dason, Ari B. for your hint and response!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert a "container" (environment) to a character string because an environment does not posses such a property. If you want the name of the variable where the environment is stored and was passed as argument to function `y`, then use the solution proposed by @Gavin above.

OTOH, if you want to dump the environment contents, then use this:

```
y = function(myEnv) {
  print(as.list(myEnv))
}
```

BTW, I must point out that I don't understand why do you run `evalq({    }, tenv)`. It doesn't change the environment. Try the following (after running your commands):

```
> uenv <- new.env()
> identical(as.list(uenv),as.list(tenv))
```

Comment: thank you to follow up my question. Yes, you are right about that I want to the name of the variable where the environment is stored and was passed as argument to function y and it is redundant for the part 'evalq{}'. So Gavin 's solution really helps. I appreciate your help very much and append to your nice tip about reading the contents of a container. The ll() in library(gdata) is another good one.